# Disposición de imágenes con la misma altura en Bootstrap 4

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Quiero que se dispongan en la misma fila, una foto a la izquierda y dos fotos a la derecha una encima de otra.Como en esta imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede setear la primera imagen para que ocupe todo el ancho del contenedor con la clase `w-100`  ya que actualmente posee las dimensiones `320*240`, y el alto con la clase `h-100`.

Aunque sería mejor tener una imagen con mayor resolución y con un tamaño acorde a lo que desea.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row" >
  <div class="col">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" class="w-100 h-100" />
  </div>

  <div class="col">
  <div class="col mb-4">
   <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240"  />
  </div>

  <div class="col">
   <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He puesto esas imágenes para que se vea algo, si le pongo todo el ancho y el alto deja de ser responsive, la idea es que se vaya redimensionando todo manteniendo la misma altura.